# calling function which was std::bind(ed) with std::ref argument

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    void fnc(int & a) { ++a; }
};

int main ()
{
    typedef std::function<void(int)> Func;

    int i = 0;
    Test t;
    Func f = std::bind(&Test::fnc, &t, std::ref(i));
    //f(); //error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
    f(37); //Here I am forced to pass evidently unused int
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Do I use it right?

Is it really necessary to pass some random int?

If so, why is that? 
Is that because the magic of templates is limited, and I actually must pass int to function taking int OR is it by design for some purposes? (e.g. to force user not to forget how the declaration of the function already looks like?)

I use vs2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No no no: What you have is a function taking *zero* arguments, because everything is bound already! You want one of the following two:

```
std::function<void()> f = std::bind(&Test::fnc, &t, std::ref(i));

std::function<void(int&)> g = std::bind(&Test::fnc, &t, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Now the following two effect `t.fnc(i)`:

```
f();  // OK, bound to `i` always.

g(i); // Same effect
```

Note that if possible you should declare the bound functions as `auto`, which is more efficient. And a third option is a closure expression, `[&i,&t](){t.fnc(i);}`.

Comment: One question, is it possible to pass by ref but provide the variable during the call, not during binding? Or if I do not want to copy whole object (int here is wrong example) I use placeholders but with pointers?

Comment: @relaxxx: Doesn't `g` precisely fit those requirements? (Note the correction I just made; it takes a *reference* now.)

Comment: Oh, yes it does. I had just stack this in my head: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind `Notes

The arguments to bind are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in std::ref or std::cref.` Did I understand it wrong, or is it wrong?

Comment: Oh! Arguments to BIND... I understand it now :) I should get some sleep :) Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where you have to look at arguments: in the call to `bind()`, where the arguments become part of the bind object, and in the call to the bind object itself, where the arguments are passed to placeholders that were established in the original call to `bind()`. In the example here, there are no placeholders in the call to `bind()`, so there is no need for any arguments in the call to the bind object. If you call it with more arguments than it needs, the extra ones are ignored.

The code here adds a layer to the bind object by wrapping it in a `std::function` object. The signature defined for the `std::function` object (here, `std::function<void(int)>`) determines how to call that object: it takes an argument of type `int` and passes that value to the bind object, which ignores it.